# How to create changing variables within a formatted string?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry for the title it's hard to explain. This code is pretty self-explanatory for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for any help!

```
handtype = ""
hand_format = 'Handtype: %s' % (handtype)
if y:
    handtype = "Straight"
    hand = hand_format

hand
```

Desired Output = 'Handtype: Straight'

Comment: Not really sure if this helps but you can look into Dictionary implementations https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to access the value by defining a function instead. Something like this:-

```
handtype = ""
hand_format = lambda : f"Handtype : {handtype}"
if y:
    handtype = "Straight"
    hand = hand_format()

hand
```

Whenever you will call `hand_format`, you will access the latest value.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `hand_format` is created once, and by changing the `handtype` , it does not change.

Only the string format should be saved in the `hand_format` variable.

You have to do this :

```
handtype = ""
hand_format = 'Handtype: %s' 
if y:
    handtype = "Straight"
    hand = hand_format % (handtype)

hand
```

If we print `hand`

```
Handtype: Straight
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to avoid doing. But perhaps there is no way around it. Thank you